# Option in Locust to run multiple Locustfile together like in Jmeter running multiple Thread Groups in Parallel

Tags: python, python-3.x, locust

I have requirement to run performance test suite, where each script will consist of set of  REST APIs for one particular functionality on a given platform, like in Loadrunner or Jmeter we can run multiple scripts together or in parallel either  using thread group in Jmeter or Controller in Loadrunner. Is it the same possible on Locust??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just import your User classes into a "combination locustfile"!

Lets say your users are called `User1/User2` and is defined in files called `user1.py/user2.py`

Then you can define a third file called, for example, `user1_plus_user2.py` with the following content:

```
from user1 import User1
from user2 import User2
```

And then launch it using `locust -f user1_plus_user2.py`

You can also adjust their weighting from your combination file, by doing things like

```
User1.weight = 5
User2.weight = 1
```

Comment: thanks, let me give a try...do u have any sample code by any chance

Answer (score 0):

No it's not. We achieved it by running pararell jenkins builds next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

In Locust every test is group/scenario/case is represented by a Locust User. You could develop several Users with all the tests scripts that you need to run and execute all of them in a single parallel Locust run configuration.